# Can we have a proper class of infinitely descending infinite ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, ordinal-numbers

Working in $\sf ZF-Reg.$, can we have a transitive model $M$ of $\sf ZF$ such that there exists a proper class (i.e. a subset of $M$ that is not an element of $M$) of infinitely descending infinite ordinals in $M$.

Now $\alpha$ is to be called infinitely descending infinite ordinal in $M$ if and only if $\alpha$ is a set that $M$ sees as an infinite successor von Neumann ordinal but externally it has a subset of it that is an infinitely descending membership chain beginning with $\alpha-1$, i.e. we have $\{\alpha-1, \alpha -2, \alpha-3, ...\} \subset \alpha$, where each $\alpha-n = \alpha -n-1 \cup \{\alpha -n-1\}$ for all $n=0,1,2,...$

Comment: Ordinals are absolute between transitive models, so such a subset would have to be a set of "real" ordinals, and that can't happen.

Comment: @Wojowu, the ambient theory of models here is $\sf ZF−Reg. $ and not $\sf ZF$, and a transitive model here is in this ambience, so it can have non-standard ordinals. In other words, the absolutness argument of ordinals in transitive models (where the ambient theory of models is taken to be $\sf ZFC$), doesn't apply to the case here.

Comment: @Wojowu When regularity is dropped from the metatheory, weird things can happen in terms of transitive models - see e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017399/without-foundation-not-transitive-model-of-zfc/3017529#3017529) for an extreme example! (Of course, that also means one has to be extremely careful with one's definitions - in particular, if "von Neuman ordinal" means "hereditarily transitive set," then $\mathsf{ZF-Reg}$ can't even prove that the vNos are linearly ordered by $\in$ since Quine atoms are technically vNos by this definition).

Comment: @NoahSchweber You're right we have to be careful with that we even mean with "ordinals". I believe one characterization of (well-founded) von Neumann ordinals valid in ZF-Reg is as transitive sets (strictly) totally ordered by $\in$. Isn't this enough to show they are absolute between transitive models?

Comment: @Wojowu, per your last definition those can be non-well founded since a strict total order is not necessarily a well-order. Now call those as *strict ordinals" to discriminate them from *well ordinals" which are the von Neumanns. Now perhaps the notion of strict ordinals is absolute beween transitive models of $\sf ZF$ even over non-well founded transitive models, but this won't mean that the notion of "well ordinal" is absolute over those, i.e. you can have strict ordinals that some of these models see as well ordinals, but others see them as strict ordinals that are not well ordinals.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Just because it is not explicitly mentioned it doesn't mean that it doesn't follow from the definitions - over ZF, "strict ordinals" and "well ordinals" are the same thing. However, this is no longer the case over ZF-Reg, contrary to my claim in the previous comment (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1829930/127263)). I stand corrected on that claim.

Comment: @Wojowu, I know that, I'm not speaking about this issue. You asked in your last comment  "Isn't this enough to show they are absolute between transitive models?" and here the question is about well ordinals and strict ordinals in my terminology. The answer I gave is that even if strict ordinals are absolute over transitive models of ZF (whether well founded or not) this doesn't mean that well ordinals are! It is absolutness over well ordinals in this respect that would falsify my question outright, which is not there. Absolutness of strict ordinals won't touch it.

Comment: My argument was that it would follow if strict and well ordinals were equivalent, which I thought was the case. I now see that's where my mistake was.

Comment: @Wojowu, Yes. But there is something nice about your question, which would translate in my terminology to: is the notion of "strict ordinal" absolute over all transitive models of $\sf ZF$? (ambient theory for models being $\sf ZF-Reg.$). I tend to think it is but I don't have a proof. I think this deserves to be raised as a separate question. Thanks.